# Reliability of mount/umount

Tags: linux, mount

We have our customer's ftp root tailored by creating "virtual" directories with mount. This means that we have some hundred directories mounted with the `bind` option.

Lately we've experienced problems where directories just won't unmount until we run `umount` several times, `-lrf` in different combinations doesn't even work. No error is presented by `umount`, but when I run `rmdir` it tells me `Device or resource busy`.

Should I expect this behaviour when we've mounted this amount of directories, or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I have solved this.

I think the main problem was `umount /path/to/ftp/dir/*`. Replaced it with `umount /path/to/ftp/dir/sub1`, `umount /path/to/ftp/dir/sub2`, etc.

Also I don't use `-l` or any other modifier anymore. I probably need to review that, but for now this works best.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `lsof` command to see if there are still open files in the offending path?

Comment: running `lsof | grep the/path/in/question` doesn't return anything

Comment: Neither does `lsof +D the/path/in/question` or `fuser -v the/path/in/question`

Comment: That's strange.  I have only seen the error when I forget and there's a process running using a file in the path.